# Using a Common Table Expression for a simple select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression

I've noticed in our project the following use of a Common Table Expression to perform a simple select from a view:

```
WITH CTE_View_Alias AS
(
  SELECT 
    Id,
    Column1,
    Column2
  FROM VW_View
),
CTE_Foo AS
(
  SELECT
    B.Bar_Id,
    V.Column1
  FROM VW_Bar B
  INNER JOIN CTE_View_Alias V
    ON B.View_Id = V.Id
)
```

The CTE is only used in one other place, another CTE.  The columns in the CTE are a subset of the view's columns.

Is there a benefit to using this?  Why not directly reference the view?  Unfortunately, the originator of these sql statements is no longer with the company.  To me, this reduces readability but I don't want to eliminate it if there's a reason my inexperience prevents me from seeing.

Comment: Is CTE_View_Alias being referenced multiple times in the query? CTE is like a temporary result set. It can be referenced multiple times without going to the actual view (or table) multiple times.

Comment: No, it's used once in another CTE.

Comment: How many columns are in the view queried in the CTE?  Meaning, does the CTE reference all the columns in the view?  And what version - CTEs are SQL Server 2005+ functionality.

Comment: The columns in the CTE are a subset of the view columns.  Version: SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference between:

```
WITH CTE_View_Alias AS (
 SELECT v.id,
        v.column1,
        v.column2
   FROM VW_View v)
SELECT t.*
  FROM CTE_View_Alias t
```

...and:

```
SELECT v.id,
       v.column1,
       v.column2
  FROM VW_View v
```

It's plausible the view isn't necessary either, but that's not the question posed...

There is no performance difference between the previously mentioned options vs a derived table either:

```
 SELECT x.*
   FROM (SELECT v.id,
                v.column1,
                v.column2
           FROM VW_View v) x
```

The CTE is syntactic sugar for a derived table, ***if not using recursive functionality***.

#### Conclusion

You'll have to ask the author why they chose to use a CTE.  It possible there were more complex operations that were removed & the CTE was left as-is in the fear of breaking something unforeseen.  Or it's just functionality they *wanted* to use...

I always fear that questions like these are too abstracted/simplified to demonstrate decisions.

Comment: I can't ask the author, they are no longer with the company.  Although I understand your reservations for answering the question in the larger context, I really just wanted the smaller answer you gave at the start of your answer.  It sounds like there are no efficiency gains from using one over the other.

Comment: @rboone: I often find myself implementing a chain of CTEs that ends as follows: `…, SomethingFinal AS (…) SELECT * FROM SomethingFinal`. What's the use, you'd ask? Well, when debugging the query, it is convenient to just comment the last select and add a different one: `SELECT * FROM SomethingIntermediate`. That is, you can easily verify the output of any of the CTEs that make up your query.

Comment: Andriy M: That makes sense.  If I wanted to take a look at the important data in that table while building my query, it would take less time to do a select * from the cte rather than specifying the limited column set that was pertinent.  I appreciate the insight as I am learning when it comes to databases.